# Django contains None (or reversed contain)

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering if there's a non-customized (so no custom method) way to invert the results of `__contain` in the Django Admin URL getter.

Two ways I wish I could check

- The value is equal to `None`
- The value is NOT equal to query-value

Something like this:

`http://localhost:8000/admin/item/?icon__not_contains=SomeFolderInMyPath`
`http://localhost:8000/admin/item/?icon__contains=None`

I could make a custom method, so no examples are needed for that. Just trying to explore the possibilities of the basic Django functionalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the reverse of `__contains`:

```
from django.db.models import Q

qs = MyModel.objects.filter(~Q(icon__contains='any string'))
```

If you want to check if value is `None` you could use [isnull](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std%3afieldlookup-isnull) e.g. Do not include those objects for which icon is None:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(icon__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already know that method :). I was just wondering if there was any native Django call for it. Maybe I could tweak the `Core` by adding the `__not_contains` URI-function to always do that method. Thanks anyway :)